# Java array minimum element within for-loop

Tags: java, arrays

OK, I have been at it for a long time now. I have looked after similar problems here in stack-overflow and I still can't make it work. I need to find the maximum values within an array and minimum values. Trying to find the minimum is the problem. I have literately tried everything from writing separate methods and so on and still the output in 0. Here is what I have tried:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ArrayMin {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a[] = new int[10];
    int max = a[0];
    int min = a[0];

    System.out.println("Enter elements of array :");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      a[i] = scanner.nextInt();
      if (i == 9)
        break;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {

      if (a[i] > max)
        max = a[i];

      else if (a[i] < min)
        min = a[i];

    }

    System.out.println("Result is max is :" + (max)); //if I input 1-10, output is 10
    System.out.println("Result is min is :" + (min)); //whatever number I input the output is always 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Using a debugger to go through your code step by step should give you the answer quickly...

Comment: You initialize min to 0. So if you input numbers from `[1-10]` the min will always be 0. Also remove the if with the break in your for loop.

Comment: `if (i==9) break;` is redundant.  If you take it out, `i` will be incremented to 10 and then the loop will exit because the `i<10` condition is no longer true.  Which is what you want.

Comment: @ajb Alright i will keep that in mind, good to know. The problem I was solving had a "sample starter" code written to begin with so I did not want to mess anything up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare your array, it's initialized to all zeroes.  Then you assign the `min` to your first element, which is zero.  Presumably all values are >= to 0 once they're assigned, so the `min` is still zero, but the `max` is correct.

Establish your `max` and `min` *after* the `for` loop where you assign input values to the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  a[i] = scanner.nextInt();
  if (i == 9)
    break;
}
// Moved HERE.
int max = a[0];
int min = a[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this.

```
   int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
...
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

      if (a[i] > max)
        max = a[i];

      if (a[i] < min)
        min = a[i];

    }
...
```